# Не работает авторизация и php код в echo

Tags: php

Допустим есть 2 input поля. Логин и пароль. Они заданы как переменные в скрипте: например логин=admin, а пароль=admin. Есть другой файл где прописана функция phpinfo и есть несколько полей.
Как сделать так, чтобы при правильном логине и пароле, были показаны результаты phpinfo и несколько полей, а при неправильном авторизации было написано "Доступ запрещен"
Пробовал так, но не работает:

Все должно быть в одном файле и желательно без использования БД
    <?

```
$login_user=“admin”;

$password_user=“admin”;

$login=$POST[‘login’];

$password=$POST[‘password’];

if( ($login_user == $login) and ($password_user == $password) )

{

echo "<? phpinfo(); ?>`<input type="text" name="title"><input type="submit" value="редактировать">`";

}

else

{

echo "Доступ запрещен";

}

?>

    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="login">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Вход">
    </form>
```

Comment: @dimkachel, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Смените `$POST` на `$_POST` (добавилось подчеркивание), и все заработает.